# Cannot create automation object - lotusscript

Tags: dllimport, lotusscript

I have a dll which is registered in GAC and declared in my form. I am using Notes 9 and windows 7. The declaration -

Declare Function CreateAccount Lib

> "c:\Program Files (x86)\PwC\SDCADInstall\SDCADLib.dll" (sADServer As
>   String , sUserID As String  ,sPassword As String  , sRoot As String,
>   sLocation As String  , sLoS As String   , sSBU As String  , sFName As
>   String, sLName As String , sADId As String  , sDescription As String 
>   , sOffice As String ) As String

I am getting "Cannot create automation object" error while creating the object. The parameter values are collected by another function. Pl find the code below :

```
Dim obj As Variant
enter code here
Set obj = CreateObject("SDCADLib.Account") 
retval =  obj.CreateAccount(sADServer , sUserID  ,sPassword  , sRoot, sLocation  , sLoS   , sSBU  , sFName, sLName , sADId  , sDescription  , sOffice )
CreateADAccount = retval
```

I am stuck here for ages. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused because you include a Lib declaration, which is not necessary if you are using CreateObject to access your DLL from LotusScript via COM.

Since you mention the GAC, I presume you have written your DLL as a .NET assembly. Have you seen [this IBM Technote about calling .NET classes from LotusScript](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230705) and followed the instructions there? Specifically, have you followed the instruction that tells you that you have to run regasm in order to publish your DLL via COM. Without that, CreateObject won't find it.